# How to put the completed downloads in a directory with aria2c?

Tags: scientific-linux, bittorrent

```
alias download='while true; do timeout -s 9 1260 aria2c *.torrent --lowest-speed-limit=1024 --disable-ipv6=true --seed-time=0 --max-connection-per-server=6 --enable-rpc=false; sleep 1; done'
alias seed='aria2c --check-integrity=false --bt-seed-unverified=true --lowest-speed-limit=1024 --disable-ipv6=true --max-connection-per-server=6 -d . *.torrent --seed-time=999999 --seed-ratio=999999.0'
```

So I'm using these aliases with aria2 to download torrent files. Theres only 1 problem with this: how can I put the finished downloads in a directory? (using the "download" alias)

p.s.: the "while true..." in the "download" alias is there because the download "slows down"... after a while, and I need to restart aria2c :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *p.s.* strikes me as a bad idea given the way BT works*, but a proper [event hook](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#event-hook) should do the trick:

> Let's see an example of how arguments are passed to command:
>
> ```
> $ cat hook.sh
> #!/bin/sh
> echo "Called with [$1] [$2] [$3]"
> $ aria2c --on-download-complete hook.sh http://example.org/file.iso
> Called with [1] [1] [/path/to/file.iso]
> ```

The [`--seed-time` and `--seed-ratio` options](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption--seed-ratio) kind of automate many use-cases, too.

(*** better check your [settings](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/UsageExample#) and read up on BitTorrent)

Comment: When using a magnet link, the `--on-download-complete` hook seems to be called when the torrent file is downloaded, before the actual files have started downloading. `--on-bt-download-complete` might work better. Was trying [this script](http://shanhe.me/2015/07/07/moving-completed-downloads-to-a-different-directory-in-aria2).